# {Action name} isn't responding right now. Try again soon

Tags: azure, express, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I'm new with the ActionSDK and I created an project with the Action SDK.
The fulfillment of my actions is deploy in Azure as a web service.

I've being updating my action with:

> gactions update --action_package action.json --project "projectID"

this being said, the update is successful.

this is my action.json:

```
 {
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "MAIN",
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "talk to Conduent Helper",
            "Talk to conduent help"
          ]
        }
      },
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "conduentHelpTest"
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "conduentHelpApp": {
      "name": "conduentHelpTest",
      "url": "https://dialogflowappnc.azurewebsites.net",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    } 
  }
}
```

this is a fulfillment code I found after trying my own and had no success with it:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exps = express();

const ApiAiApp = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;

exps.use(bodyParser.json());

// API.AI actions
const WELCOME_ACTION = 'input.welcome';

exps.post('/', function(request, response) {

  console.log("hello World");

  const app = new ApiAiApp({request, response});
  function greetUser (app) {
    app.tell("Hello World!");
  }

  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set(WELCOME_ACTION, greetUser);

  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});

exps.listen((process.env.PORT || 7001), function() {
    console.log("App up and running, listening.")
})
```

Whenever I test in the simulator the response is:

> {Action name} isn't responding right now. Try again soon.

Whenever I do an update with the command above I see in my web service a request. But when I try to test the action in the simulator I see no request being made.

If someone can point me in the right direction. Point out any knowledge I most gain before proceeding. I there's more info I need to provide let me know and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not have enough points to comment but We are currently experiencing an outage you can see here if you are being impacted https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

[image]

You will want to monitor the Azure Status Page for further updates. Unfortunately we cannot do anything until the problem has been mitigated by engineering.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential issues:

First - you haven't shown your package.json file, but the code suggests you're using an older version of the actions-on-google library. So the code itself may not be running. Check your runtime logs to make sure it is.

Next, you've specified that it should be listening on port 7001, but the URL you've provided in the actions.json file doesn't include the port number. If that is the host and port it is running on, and you haven't provided a proxy of some sort, then you need to specify the URL as `https://dialogflowappnc.azurewebsites.net:7001/`

Also, if you're running on port 7001, you likely haven't opened up the firewall to access it.

But it seems likely you're running a proxy (or you should), since you also need to be providing a valid HTTPS connection with a valid SSL certificate. If this is a self-signed certificate, the connection may still be rejected.

Comment: I'm lost. I guess I have a knowledge gap. Thanks for the answer anyway. I'll see what I come up with.

Comment: Well, we're happy to try and fill the knowledge gap, but not sure what more direction to steer you in at the moment. If you can provide logs from your services showing what is working and what isn't, we might be able to help more. Good luck!